# GKE, Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring and custom log format

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to use **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring** to monitor my GKE cluster (as opposed to **Legacy Stackdriver**), as this is recommended by https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/ page (despite being beta).

However, I'd like to use custom log parses, as some of my containers use proprietary log formats.

My understanding:

- it's a matter of customizing `fluentd` config map (in my case it's `fluentd-gcp-config-v1.2.6` in `kube-system` namespace), however this config map is managed by GKE and can be replaced anytime.
- with **Legacy Stackdriver** it was possible to disable the logging alone, and deploy `fluentd-gcp` manually - as described e.g. here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd
  . However, with new fancy **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring** it is not possible to disable logging anymore (and only leave metrics support).

Is there any other way to support custom log formats?

Comment: You are right. Only Legacy Stackdriver let you to disable [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/legacy-stackdriver/logging) and allow you to use [Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/). The new GKE monitoring option does not support using 'only monitoring' while 'disabling logging'. I would recommend you to file a [feature to support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) using [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187203&template=0) link to support this option with Stackdriver support for GKE

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Frankly, it makes me think about using legacy Stackdriver mode for now. I have to review what SKEM offers compared to legacy. Not being able to handle various log formats properly is a show-stopper for me.

Comment: @CodePainters have you solved this somehow? I'm stacked with the same issue here. I'd like to customize FluentD config map and to use metric (Prometheus) as it is.

Comment: @Rastko nope. But I moved to other activities temporarily, not much research done since my question, to be honest.

Comment: +1 . I try to output structured-logging such as {"severity":400,"message":"foobar"} text to stdout. But stackdriver logging output as plain text.